# Delete data before inserting into table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery which has some basic data segmented by date (main_table). I then have a new table which has the most recent 5 days worth of data (daily_transfer_table).

On a daily basis I'm looking to delete the last 5 days worth of data from my main_table, before inserting the most recent 5 days from the daily_transfer_table.

The reason for this is that there could be an issue with recent data so I always want to refresh the last 5 days, rather than just yesterday.

I'm not sure if this can be done with delete and insert or if I should be using another structure?

Many thanks for any help.

Mark

Comment: Is your use case covered by either of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885484/combining-bigquery-delete-and-insert-statements/69094738#69094738 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the merge statement. From what I understand, this example [example of merging two tables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-statement-sql-explained/) is exactly what you need

Comment: Thanks the explanation on geeksforgeeks was useful, I'm going to give this a go.

Comment: Thanks for this, finally got round to working on it as I had another problem in my way (replace & cast which is now resolved).  I've managed to get this to work using merge. I'm delighted so thanks. Seems to be working perfectly. I'll post an answer to my own question, not sure if that's the right thing to do but hopefully ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a couple of options here, consider the following approaches:

1. As OjtamOjtam said, perform a merge. Depending on how much data there is though this might be more overhead than it is worth.
2. Perform a truncate prior to the insert, this would delete are the rows but keep the schema intact.  This is probably the simplest approach, but if the schema changes may not be your best approach.
3. Delete the table as a whole and recreate.  Very similar to the truncate with the big difference being you will need to recreate your table.  This may be beneficial if you think the schema may change.
4. Partition your table by ingestion time and constantly insert, potentially with a data expiration policy.  This would allow you to be able to query the table very easily, just filtering based on the partition date and allow your data expiration policy to clear out old data.  Again this would suffer from schema evolution but could be very effective for you.

Some helpful links:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#truncate_table_statement
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#table-expiration
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: I second the partitioned table with partition expirations recommendation. Probably the least frills solution.

Comment: great thanks for the advice. The amount of rows isn't huge, maybe 4,000 covering a 5 day period. The schema will always stay the same too. I think I'll try both Merge and Partitioning too for my knowledge. I've got a small problem with my data at the moment which I'm learning how to fix then I'll start with merge. many thanks

Comment: You are welcome.  If you found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting.

Comment: Thanks again for this, I've added a comment above but I've got this working now with Merge, took me a while but I'm there with it. My rep isn't high enough to be able to vote at the moment but upvote when I can!     Ill post my solution as an answer as that's what I've used there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I've ended up going down the merge route for the moment though I will explore partitions too.

Right now my query is below which strips out all rows in the target table where they are matched in the source (just using a single date column), and then re-inserts all of the data from the source. not sure if its the most efficient but its working well now. It's great being able to get it to work :)

query;

```
MERGE `data-studio-reporting.testing.target` AS target_data

USING `data-studio-reporting.testing.source` as temp_source_data

ON (target_data.Date = temp_source_data.Date)

WHEN MATCHED 

THEN DELETE

WHEN NOT MATCHED 

THEN INSERT (Date, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6)
VALUES (Date, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6)
```

my columns aren't named 1, 2, 3, 4 etc but just for ease I've used above.